# routing issues with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am novice to AngularJS. I was using `router`to move from one form to another, but I dono't know why , my routing is not working properly and it showing **Loading failed for the  with source** error.

This is my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/jE195zsrQjc6pO8Ftrzw

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: There're a lot of "errors" in your architecture. Your application module (ngApp) is never declared. You declare 3 times an app module (line 3.4.6)

Comment: actually i have used sub-folder for controller and for routing, that's why i have included module

Comment: add `ng-app="myapp"` to your index.html, don't put one controller inside another one, redirect with `redirectTo: '/admin'`, use parameters with right capital letters `templateUrl: 'admin.html',`

Comment: Thanks @AlekseySolovey